# sed command produces error when output reused (Escaping)

Tags: bash, sed, escaping

My Bash script works through a top_directory and I need the path relative to the top_directory, as the whole tree might be copied somewhere else.

I am using sed to replace the path "$TOP" to the top_directory from the filename $F1. This works, but when I place my sed command in inverted quotes  to set a shell-variable, I get an error from sed. My assumption is, that the inverted quotes require a rework on some of the escapes inside sed. But which?

Script Snippet

```
echo $F1
echo $TOP
echo $F1 | sed "s/${TOP//\//\\/}//g;s/^\///g;s/^/\"/g;s/$/\";/g"
echo fine
RELATIVE_PATH=` echo $F1 | sed "s/${TOP//\//\\/}//g;s/^\///g;s/^/\"/g;s/$/\"/g" `
echo bad
```

The first s remove the text stored in $TOP; the second s takes care of a leading slash; the third s creates a leading quote and the last a trailing quote.

OUTPUT:

```
/home/felix/data/media/music/branch/20170504/Music/Frank Reid/Frank Reid plays Just for You/04 Dorney Wood - S2x40 (digitized).mp3
/home/felix/data/media/music/branch/20170504/Music
"Frank Reid/Frank Reid plays Just for You/04 Dorney Wood - S2x40 (digitized).mp3";
fine
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'
bad
```

I also tried single quotes as escape character for the variable assignment and it failed. Also creating with sed a text like RELATIVE_PATH=".." and placing it in eval  failed.

Comment: Hi Luiz, two things I learned: I should get used to $( ) syntax and the # for sed; Many thanks

Comment: I use now: RELATIVE_PATH=$( echo $F1 | sed -e "s#$TOP##g;s#^/##g;" )

Answer (score 1):

Sed allows to use a different character than '/' as expression separator: `s#pattern#subst#g`. So your command will be simpler since you get rid of escapes and string substitution in $TOP variable

`TOP='/aa/bb'; relative=$(echo "/aa/bb/cc" | sed -e "s#$TOP##g;"' s#^/##g; s#^#"#g; s#$#"#g'); echo $relative
"cc"`

Also, $( ) is more readable than backticks `.

Even simpler as you still get a quoted string

`TOP='/aa/bb'; relative=$(echo "/aa/bb/cc" | sed -e "s#$TOP##g;"' s#^/##g;'); echo "'$relative'"
'cc'`